# Как установить файл с расширением .bundle?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

Как установить фаил VMware-Horizon-Client-4.9.0-9507999.x64.bundle на ubuntu16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить права на исполнение chmod +x VMware-Horizon-Client-4.9.0-9507999.x64.bundle и потом просто запустить ./VMware-Horizon-Client-4.9.0-9507999.x64.bundle

Comment: Возможно потребуется запуск из-под суперпользователя: ``sudo ./VMware-Horizon-Client-4.9.0-9507999.x64.bundle``